# HTML button to save div content using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, file, button, save

I need to save content of div using pure javascript.
I just edited one fiddle but I can't make it works :(

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BHeMz/254/)

```
<div id="content">
<h1>Hello world</h1>
<i>Hi everybody</i>
```

Download

```
function download(){
    var a = document.body.appendChild(
        document.createElement("a")
    );
    a.download = "export.html";
    a.href = "data:text/html," + document.getElementById("content");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Close, you need innerHTML & trigger the click too:

```
function download(){
    var a = document.body.appendChild(
        document.createElement("a")
    );
    a.download = "export.html";
    a.href = "data:text/html," + document.getElementById("content").innerHTML; // Grab the HTML
    a.click(); // Trigger a click on the element
}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/evx9stLb/)

Comment: Works great! Thank you soooo much fr your help! :)

Can I add a charset to the data?

Comment: Sure, just add `;charset=` after the text/html bit

Comment: @Cutter For IE, you should look at `window.navigator.msSaveBlob`. For Safari, you might need to have the user click on the element manually

Answer (score 3):

In your jsfiddle Java Script is configured to *onLoad*, which is why *download()* is not being invoked. Change it to *No-Wrap*, then you will be able invoke *download()* on *onClick* of the button.

update download() as

```js
function download(){
    var a = document.body.appendChild(
        document.createElement("a")
    );
    a.download = "export.html";
    a.href = "data:text/html," + document.getElementById("content").innerHTML;
     a.click();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree with RGraham. However, if you use `jQuery` you can do it like this.

```
<div id="content">
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
    <i>Hi everybody</i>
</div>
<button class="download">Download</button>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('.download').on('click', function(){
       $('<a />').attr({
              download: 'export.html', 
              href: "data:text/html," + $('#content').html() 
       })[0].click()
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>In jsfiddle, you can't run a javascript function inside of html events (like onClick) unless the javascript is contained in  tags.</strike> (nevermind this)

Try this:

HTML

```
<div id="content">
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
    <i>Hi everybody</i>
</div>
<button id="download">Download</button>
```

JS

```
var download_button = document.getElementById('download');
download_button.onclick = download;

function download(){
    var content = document.getElementById('content')
    console.log(content);
}
```

[updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BHeMz/255/)

Comment: Odd, every time I try that on jsfiddle, it doesn't recognize the function

Comment: sometimes jfiddle renders the output incorrectly. Try to create a new jfiddle and paste the code n try.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a "SaveFilePicker" to save directly to the folder of your choice without triggering the more restrictive download mechanisms of the previous methods. You can save any type of items.

```
<div id="content">
<h1>Hello world</h1>
<i>Hi everybody</i>
</div>
<button onmousedown="saveAs()" class="saveAs">saveAs</button>
<script>
async function saveAs(){
fileHandler = await window.showSaveFilePicker();
const file = await fileHandler.createWritable();
await file.write(document.querySelector('#content').innerHTML);
await file.close();
}
</script>
```

Here is a working [www.w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com) : https://leseditionslyriques.w3spaces.com/Save-Div-Content-On-Your-Computer.html