# how to open save as dialog box of browser with javascript or other language?

Tags: javascript, jquery, save-as

everyone.

I've built a site to parse online video url. eg: [facebook video downloader](http://v.atob.site/facebook.html)

I can get the real video address by using python Crawler.

My problem is: after getting the real video address, how can I open the **saveAS Dialog box** of browser *by click any button*?

Now the user has to right click and select "saveAS" menu item.

[sorry, but you can see the image at here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fUKN.png)

Comment: see [Html Button to Save](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29702870/7081346) ( on stackoverflow ) if it is a video URI then change datatype in `data:`.

Comment: try this
[Try This thread, it may work for you and let me know as well :-)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336663/how-to-make-a-browser-display-a-save-as-dialog-so-the-user-can-save-the-conten)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the cross-browser Javascript "Save As" dialog on GitHub:
https://github.com/koffsyrup/FileSaver.js