# How to make user to export design from website

Tags: javascript, html

User can design stuff in site and export the project as HTML if they needed. How can I make user to download design in html format?

Comment: This question is liable to **downvotes** since you didn't adequately explain a scenario and what you have so far.

Comment: Created a website builder I want user to export design that he created to html format

Comment: You need to substantially edit your code and give an example of how to export the project. It seems very unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean but if you put the design stuff in a div. You can download that div in an html format.

```js
function download(){
    var a = document.body.appendChild(
        document.createElement("a")
    );
    a.download = "export.html";
    a.href = "data:text/html," + document.getElementById("content").innerHTML;
    a.click();
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
    <i>Hi everybody</i>
</div>
<button onClick="download()">Download</button>
```

like this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/evx9stLb/

from this so.

[HTML button to save div content using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29702758/html-button-to-save-div-content-using-javascript)